# Knockout JS SPA + RequireJS - bundle path issue

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, gulp, yeoman, single-page-application

I have generated a knockout JS yeoman template using the knockout generator 'generator-ko' written by Steve Sanderson. It generates a ready made setup for an single page application and includes requireJS optimization configuration support in the included gulp file using Steve's own gulp-requirejs-bundler.

The bundler plugin creates .js files for each bundle you set in the optimizer config in the output folder.

The issue I'm having is that requireJS will ALWAYS try to load these bundle JS files from the *current* path instead of the *root* site path. Remember that I'm using an SPA, so folders are not "real".

eg if you access: 
www.mysite.com/event/dashboard

then it will try to load event-dashboard.js (the bundled module) from: www.mysite.com/event/event-dashboard.js

Obviously that location doesnt exist being a SPA so it fails.

I need a way to control where requireJS loads these bundles from but I dont know where this can be configured.

Having looked under the hood of Steve's gulp-requirejs-bundler plugin, I'm thinking the problem may lie in the way requireJS loads the bundles.

Here's the issue raised on the gulp plugin:
https://github.com/SteveSanderson/gulp-requirejs-bundler/issues/4#

It doesnt seem that there's alot of activity going on around this so not sure if i'll get a reply anytime soon there.

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this or has any advice.

Note: the only modification I have made is swapped out hasher for History.js so that urls dont use a hashbang to control the client side page routing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution though it's not ideal using this:
https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Fine-grained-URL-control

In the index.html file, I can override the requireJS.load() function to modify the url from a relative path (ie beginning with "./") to the root path (ie "/")

```
<!-- build:js /scripts.js -->
<script src="/app/require.config.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_modules/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<script>
 (function () {
   var load = requirejs.load;
   requirejs.load = function (context, moduleId, url) {
  //modify url here, then call original load
  return load(context, moduleId, url.replace("./", "/"));
};

//Now load code.
require(['app/startup']);
}());
</script>
```

Note that I also had to remove the data-main="app/startup" from the require.js script tag.

Still think there's surely a better way than doing this though.